# Can the Postgres array overlap (&&) operator use an index?

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with an indexed array column:

```
CREATE TABLE mention (
  id SERIAL,
  phraseIds integer[],
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX indx_mentions_phraseIds on mention USING GIN (phraseids public.gin__int_ops);
```

Queries using the "overlaps" operator on this column don't seem to use the index:

```
explain analyze select m.id FROM mention m WHERE m.phraseIds && ARRAY[11638,11639];

Seq Scan on mention m  (cost=0.00..933723.44 rows=1404 width=4) (actual time=103.018..3751.525 rows=1101 loops=1)
Filter: (phraseids && '{11638,11639}'::integer[])
Rows Removed by Filter: 7019974
Total runtime: 3751.618 ms
```

Is it possible to get Postgresql to use the index? Or should we be doing something else?

Update: I repeated the test with 'SET enable_seqscan TO off' and the index is still not used.

Update: I should have mentioned that I am using 9.2 with the intarray extension.

Update: It seems that the intarray extension is part of this problem. I re-created the table without using the intarray extension and the index is used as expected. Anyone know how to get the index to be used with the intarray extension? The docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/intarray.html) say that indexes are supported for &&.

Comment: Use `SET enable_seqscan TO off` and see first if PG *can* use the index, it should, and then if the index scan will be faster than the seq scan. Post the result here, please.

Comment: Why is storing an *array* of id numbers in each row the best design for your table?

Comment: The data was previously in MySQL and we used a number of separate columns (phrase0, phrase1, ...) to hold the data. Using a separate table was very slow on MySQL (many millions of rows in both tables and we need to sort the result and do limit). Using a Postgres array seemed like a good thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I built a similar table in PostgreSQL 9.2; the difference was `USING GIN (phraseids);` I don't seem to have int_ops available in this context for some reason. I loaded a few thousand rows of random (ish) data.

Setting enable_seqscan off let PostgreSQL use the index.

PostgreSQL calculated the cost of a sequential scan to be less than the cost of a bitmap heap scan. The actual time of a sequential scan was 10% the actual time of a bitmap heap scan, but the total run time for a sequential scan was a little more than the total run time of a bitmap heap scan.

Comment: Ok. Not using the intarray extension on the index for this column sorts it out. Thats what we are going to do for now. Tx.